# How to create custom 3D looking button in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, gradient, qpainter

I'm trying to create the following custom button:

[image: custom button]
To do this I've create the class and overrided `paintEvent`:

```
void Widget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

    QPen pen(Qt::darkGray, 7, Qt::SolidLine, Qt::RoundCap, Qt::RoundJoin);
    painter.setPen(pen);
    painter.drawEllipse(QPointF(width()/2, height()/2), width()/2.1,height()/2.1);

    QPen pen2(Qt::lightGray, 3, Qt::SolidLine, Qt::RoundCap, Qt::RoundJoin);
    painter.setPen(pen2);
    painter.drawEllipse(QPointF(width()/2, height()/2), width()/2.15, height()/2.15);

    QPen pen1(Qt::gray, 1, Qt::SolidLine, Qt::RoundCap, Qt::RoundJoin);
    painter.setPen(pen1);
    painter.drawEllipse(QPointF(width()/2, height()/2), width()/3.5, height()/3.5);
}
```

But, I'm not able to create the button like below with appropriate gradients and picture in the center.
Can you please help me?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? (your code seem in the correct direction)

Comment: The problem is button like effect and color as in the picture.

Comment: It is possible to draw such a button via QPainter but it is not the most straightforward method. The button image you posted has most likely been created in software like photoshop and exported and used as an image in the application.

Comment: Yes it's possible

Answer (score 3):

The key thing here is to make the gradients. And you cannot make gradients on strokes, only on fills. Meaning that you will have to implement the outline as a fill.

There is the button's components digested, listed in the order you should draw them:

[image]

Mind you that **only the first** component is a solid color, everything else is gradients. It is those gradients which get the effect.

In order to get gradients for the inner ring you will have to use `QPainterPath`, fist add the outer circle, and then add a slightly smaller inner circle, which will effectively punch a hole in the first circle, giving you something that looks like an outline but is actually a fill, a fill you can use a gradient on.

As mentioned in the comments - this involves a lot of operations and is not ideal. It would be preferable to have such buttons as images instead of painting them with `QPainter`.

Update: here is some more help, to show you how to draw a gradient outline in order to achieve some 3D illusion:

```
class Test : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
  public:
    Test() { resize(200, 200); }
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) {
        QPainter painter(this);
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
        painter.fillRect(rect(), Qt::gray);

        QPainterPath p;
        p.addEllipse(rect().center(), 50, 50);
        p.addEllipse(rect().center(), 45, 45);

        QLinearGradient g(QPointF(0, 50), QPointF(0, 150));
        g.setColorAt(0, Qt::white);
        g.setColorAt(1, Qt::black);

        QBrush b(g);
        painter.fillPath(p, b);

        QPainterPath p2;
        p2.addEllipse(rect().center(), 45, 45);
        p2.addEllipse(rect().center(), 40, 40);

        QLinearGradient g1(QPointF(0, 50), QPointF(0, 150));
        g1.setColorAt(0, Qt::black);
        g1.setColorAt(1, Qt::white);

        QBrush b1(g1);
        painter.fillPath(p2, b1);

        QPainterPath p3;
        p3.addEllipse(rect().center(), 40, 40);
        painter.fillPath(p3, b);
    }
};
```

And the result:

[image]

Comment: Can you bring any examples?

Comment: The problem is that I don't know to work with photoshop :(

Comment: @elgolondrino - see the answer update, it contains everything you need to be able to draw you button. You simply have to fine tune the gradients and colors.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the question reworded as:

**How to use `QPainter` to generate the given picture?**

Using `QPainter`:

1. Get a vectorial image of the button, ideally in `SVG`.
2. Look the `SVG` code to extract colors, gradients, sizes, etc.
3. Reproduce them with `QPainter`, you will see that for each `SVG` command, you have an nearly equal equivalent in `QPainte`r. `QPainterPath` will help.

Using `QPixmap`:

1. Get an `SVG` image of your button
2. Use `QSvgRenderer` to generate a `QImage` of the given size, and then convert it to a `QPixmap`.
3. Paint the `QPixmap` when required.

**Benefits of each options:**

- `QPixmap` is simpler, and allows you to switch the button aesthetic easily.
- `QSvgRenderer` allows you to manage hover easily
- `QPainter` allows you to override colors with those of the OS
- `QPainter` give you more flexibility for effects, animations, etc.